# Взять первую строку из Ajax data

Tags: ajax

Делается запрос

```
$.ajax({url: href+'?_top_ .p'}).done(function(data) {alert(data)});
```

В итоге выдается результат в две строки (добавляется запись о скорости загрузки сервера `<!-- 0.22611 -->`, убрать которую не представляется возможным)

Как вырвать из **data** первую строку?

Comment: Возьмите подстроку с нулевого индекса до первого вхождения `\n`.... Или удалить можно все, начиная с позиции `<!--`

Comment: это же ответ с сервера

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел ответ

```
data.split('\n')[1]
```

Всем откликнувшимся, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать так:

```
alert(data.substring(0,data.indexOf("\n")));
```

Вот рабочий пример кода:

```html
<button onclick="myFunction('Hello \n world!');"> Push me </button>

<script>
function myFunction(data) {
    alert(data.substring(0,data.indexOf("\n")));
}
</script>
```

Comment: Почему то в таком виде не работает, работает в таком виде data.split('\n')[1]